# Atiyah Macdonald 2.19 is a tautology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

[image]

The image reads:

> If $T_n$ is exact, that is to say, tensoring with $N$ transforms all exact sequences into exact sequences, then $N$ is said to be a *flat* $A$-module.

> Proposition 2.19: The following are equivalent for any $A$ module $N$:
> (i) $N$ is flat
> (ii) If $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M \rightarrow M'' \rightarrow 0$ is any exact sequence of $A$ modules, the tensored sequence $0 \rightarrow M' \otimes N \rightarrow M \otimes N \rightarrow M'' \otimes N \rightarrow 0$ is exact

As far as I understand, (i) and (ii) are identical: (i) says $N$ is flat, (ii) spills out the definition of flat. What is there to prove? The book says:

> (i) is implied and implied by (ii) by taking a long exact sequence and splitting into short exact sequences

I don't understand what long exact sequence I need to consider, because to me, the proposition looks like a tautology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atiyah-Macdonald says "exact sequence" to mean "long exact sequence". The definition of flatness says that tensoring preserves *long* exact sequences. Characterisation (ii) tells us that it if a module preserves *short* exact sequences on tensoring, then it *must* preserve *long* exact sequences on tensoring.

So if we are given an LES, we can break it up into SESes, apply flatness-on-SES to prove flatness-on-LES.

I was confused, since I implicitly assume "exact sequence = SES" as I am following multiple books at the same time.

Comment: "exact sequence" might also just refer to sequences $A \to B \to C$. Though I'm not too familiar with Atiyah-Macdonald...

Comment: If you already have the answer and the answer is "Read the previous section of the book", then why do you ask?

Comment: @red_trumpet: No, A-M says "A sequence of $A$-modules and $A$-homomorphisms $\cdots\to M_{i-1}\stackrel{f_i}{\to} M_i\stackrel{f_{i+1}}{\to}M_{i+1}\to\cdots$ is said to be *exact at $M_i$* if $\mathrm{Im}(f_i)=\mathrm{Ker}(f_{i+1}$. The sequence is *exact* if it is exact at each $M_i$."

Comment: @Gae.S. I was asking the question, then understood what I was missing. `math.se` is meant to be a repository of questions and answers. It is acceptable to answer your own question. I thought I should, since this seems like an easy thing to be confused by!

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I mean, I'd rather look up the definition in my book (all the more if it's the name of a section) than search it on the internet, but then again I'm not a mathematician or ever will be.

Comment: It's acceptable to answer your own question. It is at least marginally an abuse of the site to ask the question *when* you already know the answer for the sole purpose of you, yourself, giving the answer. You posted the question and answer simultaneously. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/using-stackexchange-to-post-your-own-insights-q-a-style), as well as general comments [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/answering-your-own-question), [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/providing-an-answer-for-your-own-question) cont

Comment: Basically, you weren't being upfront when posting the question, and this does not particularly issue a strong odor of good faith.

Comment: All right. I shall delete the answer then. This was not my intention at all! I wanted to document a source of confusion someone else could have. ATM is a *hard* text to self study from (at least for me) and I've been stuck on this for a day.

Comment: EDIT: brilliant, `math.se` doesn't even let me delete this :(

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention, or add appropriate explanations to the question/answer, indicating how you were confused, and that you planned to answer the question yourself.

Comment: I really don't understand why this should be deleted.